# How to check the resolvability of Clojure specs?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

`clojure.spec.alpha` allows one to use non-resolvable specs when defining a new one:

```
(s/def :foo/bar (s/or :nope :foo/foo))
```

Here, `:foo/foo` can’t be resolved and so using `:foo/bar` will raise an exception on usage:

```
(s/valid? :foo/bar 42)
;; Exception Unable to resolve spec: :foo/foo  clojure.spec.alpha/reg-resolve! (alpha.clj:69)
```

This is something that happens in my code when I make typos like `:my-ns/my-spec` instead of `::my-ns/my-spec`. I’d like to catch those with unit-tests.

Diving in the [`clojure.spec.alpha` source code](https://github.com/clojure/spec.alpha/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/spec/alpha.clj) I found I can get all specs with `(keys (s/registry))` so my test look like this:

```
(ns my-ns.spec-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
            ;; :require all the relevant namespaces to populate the
            ;; global spec registry.
            [my-ns.spec1]
            [my-ns.spec2]))

(deftest resolvable-specs
  (doseq [spec (keys (s/registry))]
    (is (resolvable? spec))))
    ;;   ^^^^^^^^^^^ placeholder; that’s the function I want
```

Unfortunately there’s not such thing as `s/resolvable?` in `clojure.spec.alpha`. The only solution I’ve found so far is to call `(s/valid? spec 42)` and assume it not raising an exception means it’s resolvable but it doesn’t check all branches:

```
(s/def :int/int int?)
(s/def :bool/bool bool?)

(s/def :my/spec (s/or :int :int/int
                      :other (s/or :bool bool/bool
                                   :nope :idont/exist)))

(s/valid? :my/spec 1) ; <- matches the :int branch
;; => true

(s/valid? :my/spec :foo)
;; Exception Unable to resolve spec: :idont/exist  clojure.spec.alpha/reg-resolve! (alpha.clj:69)
```

I checked the exception stacktrace as well as the source code to see if I could find any function to fully resolve a spec without using a test value like `42` or `:foo` above but couldn’t find any.

Is there a way check that, for a given spec, all specs it refers to in all its branches do exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do the following:

```
(ns my-ns.utils
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]))

(defn- unresolvable-spec
  [spec]
  (try
    (do (s/describe spec) nil)
    (catch Exception e
      (if-let [[_ ns* name*] (re-matches #"Unable to resolve spec: :([^/]+)/(.+)$" (.getMessage e))]
        (keyword ns* name*)
        (throw e)))))

(defn unresolvable?
  "Test if a spec is unresolvable, and if so return a sequence
   of the unresolvable specs it refers to."
  [spec]
  (cond
    (symbol? spec)
      nil

    (keyword? spec)
      (if-let [unresolvable (unresolvable-spec spec)]
        [unresolvable]
        (not-empty (distinct (unresolvable? (s/describe spec)))))

    (seq? spec)
      (case (first spec)
        or (->> spec (take-nth 2) rest (mapcat unresolvable?))
        and (->> spec rest (mapcat unresolvable?))

        ;; undecidable
        nil)

    :default (unresolvable-spec spec)))

(def resolvable? (complement unresolvable?))
```

It works on `s/and`'s and `s/or`'s, which was my minimal use-case:

```
(u/resolvable? :int/int) ;; => true
(u/resolvable? :my/spec) ;; => false
(u/unresolvable? :my/spec) ;; => (:idont/exist)
```

But it has some flaws:

- It reinvents the wheel; I think those spec-walking functions already exist somewhere in `clojure.spec.alpha`
- It relies on catching an exception then parsing its message, because (1) `clojure.spec.alpha` doesn’t have a function that doesn’t raise an exception and (2) the functions that raise one don’t use anything more specific than `Exception`

I’d be happy to accept any other answer if someone has something more robust.